GIthub Actions to OCI with Uploading Docker Image
I want to upload Docker Image of Java Spring Boot project to my OCI with Github Actions.
Can I have pipeline Script example?

This is the workflow I created:
name: Publish Docker image

on:
  release:
    types: [ published ]

env:
  IMAGE_NAME: my-org/my-image

jobs:
  push_to_registry:
  name: Push Docker image to Docker Hub
  runs-on: ubuntu-latest
  steps:
  - name: Check out the repo
    uses: actions/checkout@v4

  - name: Extract metadata (tags, labels) for Docker
    id: meta
    uses: docker/metadata-action@v5
    with:
      images: ${{ env.IMAGE_NAME }}

  - name: Update version in build.gradle.kts
    run: >-
      sed -i "s#{{VERSION_PLACEHOLDER}}#${{ steps.meta.outputs.tags }}#g" build.gradle.kts

  - name: Setup Java
    uses: actions/setup-java@v4
    with:
      distribution: 'temurin'
      java-version: 17

  - name: Setup Gradle
    uses: gradle/actions/setup-gradle@v3

  - name: Build docker image
    run: ./gradlew bootBuildImage

  - name: Tag docker image
    run: docker tag ${{ env.IMAGE_NAME }} ${{ steps.meta.outputs.tags }}

  - name: Log in to Docker Hub
    uses: docker/login-action@v3
    with:
      username: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_USERNAME }}
      password: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_PASSWORD }}

  - name: Push docker image to DockerHub
    run: docker push ${{ steps.meta.outputs.tags }}

And added this on the build.gradle.kts:
// Dockerize
tasks.named<BootBuildImage>("bootBuildImage") {
    environment.set(
        mapOf("BP_JVM_VERSION" to "17")
    )
    imageName = "my-org/my-image"
}

This will pick the tag version every time you release and publish the respective version on docker hub
